# ObjectStateEntry.GetModifiedProperties returns empty list

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using the following test code:

```
var dataEntry = dbContext.DataEntries.Where(de => de.ID == 1).Single();

dataEntry.myBooleanProp = !dataEntry.myBooleanProp;

var dataEntryObjectStateEntry = ((IObjectContextAdapter)mapi.db)
    .ObjectContext
    .ObjectStateManager
    .GetObjectStateEntry(dataEntry);

var modifiedProps = dataEntryObjectStateEntry.GetModifiedProperties();
```

Now I would consider, that my `myBooleanProp` property would be part of the `modifiedProps` list. However, the list has a length of 0. But why?

**PS:**

`dataEntryObjectStateEntry.OriginalValues["myBooleanProp"]` and `dataEntryObjectStateEntry.CurrentValues["myBooleanProp"]` each contain the correct values.

Comment: What is `mapi.db`? Why not `((IObjectContextAdapter)dbContext)`?

Comment: @strickt01 `mapi.db` is my `dbContext`. MAPI is a wrapper for the dbContext, which provides some additional information we require in our software. and the `db` property contains the actual context.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. In my scenario, it is required to call `dbContext.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();` beforehand. Only after that, Entity Framework actually sets the "modified" flags for all entities. And that's what's required for the `GetModifiedProperties()` method to work.